# first selector doesn't filter first, but first-child does

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, jquery-selectors

I've used first many times but this time it doesn't work and no errors in console.
I have this html:

```
<ul>
<li class="iheader"><h1>TITLE</h1></li>
//some more list items
<li class="iheader"></li> 
</ul>
```

Now running this code :

```
$('.iheader:first').removeClass('iheader');
```

Removes both classes. I've also tried :

```
$('.iheader').filter(':first').removeClass('iheader');
```

And same result.

However if i use `first:child` it does work when the html is as mentioned above.

anyone may know why? could this be related to the fact that i'm including jQuery mobile?

Comment: Works in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/29HKU/. The problem must lie elsewhere in your code.

Comment: For some reason @acme solution worked for me, you happen to know why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
$('.iheader:first-child').removeClass('iheader');
```

Comment: @eric.itzhak: are you sure you're not calling the code multiple times? That's the only explanation I can think of... (& what version of jQuery are you using?)

Comment: Your code should work, too (as the other guys have fiddled out) - I guess the problem is somewhere else. But as long as this is working, just use it ;-)

Comment: @Matt ya i call it inside the ready event once and i use 1.8.3. and acme ya i'll use it but i'd really love to know why because this doesn't make sense. what made you suggest it?

Comment: I should have mentioned i am also including jQuery mobile

Answer (score 0):

With [jQuery first](http://api.jquery.com/first/):

```
$('.iheader').first().removeClass('iheader');
```

Comment: No this does the same thing.

Comment: i know, but its a suggestion to try an alternative way

Comment: Oh ya i meant i tried and it didn't work :) Thanks for trying to help!

Answer (score 0):

For those wondering why acmes solution works,
it's because jQuery has the option to use CSS selectors, and `:first-child` is a css selector which specifies css for element that is the first child of its parent.